# Passing object to a different method causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, argument-passing

I have a method which plays sound every time it's called:

```
- (void)play :(NSString *) fileName : (NSString *) extension
{
    AUGraph theAUGraph;
    ...
    AUGraphStart(theAUGraph);
    ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopPlaying) withObject:theAUGraph afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

Now after five seconds the selector calls stopPlaying method, and passes theAUGraph object:

```
-(void) stopPlaying: (AUGraph *) graph{
    AUGraphStop(graph);
}
```

The problem I encounter right away is:

```
Implicit conversion of C pointer type 'theAUGraph' (aka 'struct OpaqueAUGraph *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast.
```

---

I tried both suggested fixes:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopPlaying) withObject:(__bridge id)(theAUGraph) afterDelay:5.0];
```

and

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopPlaying) withObject:CFBridgingRelease(theAUGraph) afterDelay:5.0];
```

---

But in runtime it just crashed with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

I'm confused, how do I pass the object then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUGraph` is not an Objective-C object.

You could box it in an `NSValue`, but I would simply replace that line of code with a call to `dispatch_after()` (Xcode helpfully has a template that shows how to use `dispatch_after`).

Comment: Then how to do stop an AUGraph *after* it's done playing (aka 5 seconds)? The problem I encounter is that every time I call play method, it creates a a new thread which won't be destroyed unless I explicitly call AUGraphStop(theAUGraph).

Comment: Use `dispatch_after()` with a delay of 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different way to the same end kind of:

```
-(void)play :(NSString *) fileName : (NSString *) extension
{
    self.timer2 = nil;
    [self initializeTimer2];

    self.soundID = 0;
    NSString * soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName  ofType:extension];

           AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);

           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

           void * clientData = self;

          AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (soundID,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc,
                                                 clientData);
   }


-(void) initializeTimer2
{
    // *********************************************************
    // Create Timer by this method to be able to stop it later
    // *********************************************************

    self.timer2 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.2 target:self selector:@selector(poll2:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer2 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}

-(void) poll2:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{
    [self.timer2 invalidate];

    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (self.soundID
                                                   );

    // *******************************************************************
    // Used if device is muted. Will cause the login to dismiss
    // *******************************************************************

    if ( self.commandAccessBool == YES)
    {
        [self.delegate didConfirmUserAccount];  
    }
    if ( self.editAccessBool == YES)
    {
        [self.delegate didConfirmUserAccountEditorLevel];  
    }

}

void MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc (SystemSoundID  ssID,
                                               void * clientData)
{

    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (ssID);


    //[((UserLoginViewController *)clientData).timer2 invalidate];

    // *******************************************************************
    // The class was passed as a void *
    // We have to cast it to the class and then call the delegate method
    // *******************************************************************

    if (((UserLoginViewController *)clientData) != nil)
    {
        if ( ((UserLoginViewController *)clientData).commandAccessBool == YES)
        {
            [((UserLoginViewController *)clientData).delegate didConfirmUserAccount];  
        }

        if ( ((UserLoginViewController *)clientData).editAccessBool == YES)
        {
            [((UserLoginViewController *)clientData).delegate didConfirmUserAccountEditorLevel];  
        }
    }

}
```